# c++ string.compare don't accept space characters

Tags: c++, string, compare

First I want to apologist about my bad title. Now the problem. I'm trying to compare two strings in C++. I had try with string.compare and ==, none of them worked. Here is code

```
if(game_type == "AI vs AI"){
    std::cout<<"You choosed AI vs AI\n";
    aiVsAI(range);
}
else{
std::cerr <<"Error";
}
```

and with string.compare

```
if(game_type.compare("AI vs AI") == 0){
    std::cout<<"You choosed AI vs AI\n";
    aiVsAI(range);
}
else{
    std::cerr <<"Error";
}
```

If I give AIvsAI for input the program works correctly, but if i enter AI (space) vs (space) AI, the program prints "Error". I tried using \x20 instant of space but this didn't work too. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Print the string. I bet you'll see `AI`.

Comment: How are you obtaining `game_type`? I bet you're doing `std::cin >> game_type`, which only gets the first word.

Comment: @Greg, I don't think so, because then "AIvsAI" wouldn't work either. But I'm indeed curious what the value of `game_type` is.

Comment: @rashmatash, It would work perfectly. It's one word.

Comment: yeah, I'm optaining it via std::cin. I didn't know that this takes only the first word. If you post this as answer I will give you "best answer.

Comment: @user3868594, It's not `std::cin` that stops at spaces, it's `operator>>`.

Comment: Well I don't think to overload the >> operator for cin, but thx for the information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using a statement similar to

```
std::cin >> game_type;
```

to obtain the user input. The problem is that the `>>` operator only extracts the *first* word from the line the user types, which makes `game_type` only contain `AI` when you type `AI vs AI`. (As a side note, if you were to use `std::cin >> blah` on the next line, then `blah` would contain `vs` because that typed input had not been consumed yet.)

To fix this, you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::getline(std::cin, game_type);
```

This gets everything the user types on the line (up to but not including the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress) and puts that in `game_type`. This is almost always the right way to get user input for an interactive program.